# Biased or Unbiased Random

Tags: randomness

I am confused with the concept of completely random actions. I was thinking of a very common statistical experiment in which we have a device or black box which randomly chooses between 1 and -1. If we infinitely do this processes, we will have set of randomly chosen infinite 1's and -1's. If we sum up all the elements of this randomly generated set we will probably get 0 every time we perform this experiment.  This implies that it is a biased random as it is following the constraint that sum of elements of randomly generated infinite set is 0 every time.

But I was wondering, since the above procedure of choosing between 1 and -1 is completely random, then the sum of all the elements of randomly generated set must be a random number instead of being zero every time. If the sum of elements is any random number, then only it must be called as a unbiased random number and hence confirming the performed experiment to be random.

Comment: You might find it worth asking this question on [Phil.SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com) rather than physics as it looks likely that you're confused conceptually about what constitutes randomness; simply because a sequence is random does not mean that there are not determined quantities about it; as you've already pointed out, the mean or average is a determined number; another, very simple fact, is that we only see 0 and 1s, but that of course is tautological.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics not physics.

Comment: The conceptual confusion arises because we're using determinate in at least two different ways here.

Answer (score 3):

That's why it's preferable to be precise and say that these numbers are not simply "random numbers", but rather [random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) that follow a [probability *distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution), which, in the black box example, is the sum of two Dirac delta functions centered on $-1$ and on $+1$.